# WinDBG: Can't read debug dir

Tags: windbg

I am loading a .Net Core memory dump taken on a linux machine into the most recent WinDbg.

The `!dh` command is unable to read the debug dir. However, if I save the module to disk and run `dumpbin /headers` - the debug dir info is there.

Here we go:

```
0:000> .shell -ci "!dh 00007454`16df8000" findstr /i debug
   787C4 [      38] address [size] of Debug Directory
Debug Directories(2)
Can't read debug dir
.shell: Process exited
0:000> ? 00007454`16e70000 - 00007454`16df8000
Evaluate expression: 491520 = 00000000`00078000
0:000> .writemem c:\temp\mydll.dll 00007454`16df8000 L?00078000
Writing 78000 bytes................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
0:000> .shell """c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.37.32822\bin\Hostx64\x86\dumpbin.exe""" /headers C:\temp\mydll.dll"
<.shell waiting 1 second(s) for process>
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 14.37.32822.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


Dump of file C:\temp\mydll.dll

PE signature found

File Type: DLL

...

  Debug Directories

        Time Type        Size      RVA  Pointer
    -------- ------- -------- -------- --------
    D7F96D86 cv            88 000787FC    769FC    Format: RSDS, {BD0B7AAC-1040-4E54-97CD-0767E91C1A72}, 1, D:\_wfaz\07\3\s\....pdb
    00000000 repro          0 00000000        0
...
```

So the `!dh` extension command fails to read the debug dir, but the dumpbin reads it just fine.

This is not an idle question - I am unable to load the symbols because of it.

What am I missing?

**Appendix**

Here is the full output of the `!dh` command:

```
Opened log file 'c:\temp\dumps\1.log'
0:000> !dh 00007454`16df8000

File Type: DLL
FILE HEADER VALUES
     14C machine (i386)
       3 number of sections
9FC82936 time date stamp Sat Dec 12 08:31:34 2054

       0 file pointer to symbol table
       0 number of symbols
      E0 size of optional header
    2022 characteristics
            Executable
            App can handle >2gb addresses
            DLL

OPTIONAL HEADER VALUES
     10B magic #
   48.00 linker version
   76A00 size of code
     800 size of initialized data
       0 size of uninitialized data
   788D6 address of entry point
    2000 base of code
         ----- new -----
0000000010000000 image base
    2000 section alignment
     200 file alignment
       3 subsystem (Windows CUI)
    4.00 operating system version
    0.00 image version
    4.00 subsystem version
   7E000 size of image
     200 size of headers
       0 checksum
0000000000100000 size of stack reserve
0000000000001000 size of stack commit
0000000000100000 size of heap reserve
0000000000001000 size of heap commit
    8560  DLL characteristics
            High entropy VA supported
            Dynamic base
            NX compatible
            No structured exception handler
            Terminal server aware
       0 [       0] address [size] of Export Directory
   78884 [      4F] address [size] of Import Directory
   7A000 [     464] address [size] of Resource Directory
       0 [       0] address [size] of Exception Directory
       0 [       0] address [size] of Security Directory
   7C000 [       C] address [size] of Base Relocation Directory
   787C4 [      38] address [size] of Debug Directory
       0 [       0] address [size] of Description Directory
       0 [       0] address [size] of Special Directory
       0 [       0] address [size] of Thread Storage Directory
       0 [       0] address [size] of Load Configuration Directory
       0 [       0] address [size] of Bound Import Directory
    2000 [       8] address [size] of Import Address Table Directory
       0 [       0] address [size] of Delay Import Directory
    2008 [      48] address [size] of COR20 Header Directory
       0 [       0] address [size] of Reserved Directory


SECTION HEADER #1
   .text name
   768DC virtual size
    2000 virtual address
   76A00 size of raw data
     200 file pointer to raw data
       0 file pointer to relocation table
       0 file pointer to line numbers
       0 number of relocations
       0 number of line numbers
60000020 flags
         Code
         (no align specified)
         Execute Read


Debug Directories(2)
    Type       Size     Address  Pointer
Can't read debug dir

SECTION HEADER #2
   .rsrc name
     464 virtual size
   7A000 virtual address
     600 size of raw data
   76C00 file pointer to raw data
       0 file pointer to relocation table
       0 file pointer to line numbers
       0 number of relocations
       0 number of line numbers
40000040 flags
         Initialized Data
         (no align specified)
         Read Only

SECTION HEADER #3
  .reloc name
       C virtual size
   7C000 virtual address
     200 size of raw data
   77200 file pointer to raw data
       0 file pointer to relocation table
       0 file pointer to line numbers
       0 number of relocations
       0 number of line numbers
42000040 flags
         Initialized Data
         Discardable
         (no align specified)
         Read Only
0:000> .logclose
Closing open log file c:\temp\dumps\1.log
```

And the dumpbin output:

```
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 14.37.32822.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


Dump of file C:\temp\mydll.dll

PE signature found

File Type: DLL

FILE HEADER VALUES
             14C machine (x86)
               3 number of sections
        9FC82936 time date stamp
               0 file pointer to symbol table
               0 number of symbols
              E0 size of optional header
            2022 characteristics
                   Executable
                   Application can handle large (>2GB) addresses
                   DLL

OPTIONAL HEADER VALUES
             10B magic # (PE32)
           48.00 linker version
           76A00 size of code
             800 size of initialized data
               0 size of uninitialized data
           788D6 entry point (100788D6)
            2000 base of code
           7A000 base of data
        10000000 image base (10000000 to 1007DFFF)
            2000 section alignment
             200 file alignment
            4.00 operating system version
            0.00 image version
            4.00 subsystem version
               0 Win32 version
           7E000 size of image
             200 size of headers
               0 checksum
               3 subsystem (Windows CUI)
            8560 DLL characteristics
                   High Entropy Virtual Addresses
                   Dynamic base
                   NX compatible
                   No structured exception handler
                   Terminal Server Aware
          100000 size of stack reserve
            1000 size of stack commit
          100000 size of heap reserve
            1000 size of heap commit
               0 loader flags
              10 number of directories
               0 [       0] RVA [size] of Export Directory
           78884 [      4F] RVA [size] of Import Directory
           7A000 [     464] RVA [size] of Resource Directory
               0 [       0] RVA [size] of Exception Directory
               0 [       0] RVA [size] of Certificates Directory
           7C000 [       C] RVA [size] of Base Relocation Directory
           787C4 [      38] RVA [size] of Debug Directory
               0 [       0] RVA [size] of Architecture Directory
               0 [       0] RVA [size] of Global Pointer Directory
               0 [       0] RVA [size] of Thread Storage Directory
               0 [       0] RVA [size] of Load Configuration Directory
               0 [       0] RVA [size] of Bound Import Directory
            2000 [       8] RVA [size] of Import Address Table Directory
               0 [       0] RVA [size] of Delay Import Directory
            2008 [      48] RVA [size] of COM Descriptor Directory
               0 [       0] RVA [size] of Reserved Directory


SECTION HEADER #1
   .text name
   768DC virtual size
    2000 virtual address (10002000 to 100788DB)
   76A00 size of raw data
     200 file pointer to raw data (00000200 to 00076BFF)
       0 file pointer to relocation table
       0 file pointer to line numbers
       0 number of relocations
       0 number of line numbers
60000020 flags
         Code
         Execute Read

  Debug Directories

        Time Type        Size      RVA  Pointer
    -------- ------- -------- -------- --------
    D7F96D86 cv            88 000787FC    769FC    Format: RSDS, {BD0B7AAC-1040-4E54-97CD-0767E91C1A72}, 1, D:\_wfaz\07\3\s\....pdb
    00000000 repro          0 00000000        0

SECTION HEADER #2
   .rsrc name
     464 virtual size
   7A000 virtual address (1007A000 to 1007A463)
     600 size of raw data
   76C00 file pointer to raw data (00076C00 to 000771FF)
       0 file pointer to relocation table
       0 file pointer to line numbers
       0 number of relocations
       0 number of line numbers
40000040 flags
         Initialized Data
         Read Only

SECTION HEADER #3
  .reloc name
       C virtual size
   7C000 virtual address (1007C000 to 1007C00B)
     200 size of raw data
   77200 file pointer to raw data (00077200 to 000773FF)
       0 file pointer to relocation table
       0 file pointer to line numbers
       0 number of relocations
       0 number of line numbers
42000040 flags
         Initialized Data
         Discardable
         Read Only

  Summary

        2000 .reloc
        2000 .rsrc
       78000 .text
```

They are basically the same. Except for the debug dir, for some reason.

**EDIT 1**

The below transcript shows the output of the `.reload` and `lmvm` commands:

```
0:000> .reload /f /s xyz_common
ELFBin: No build id is found for module 'System.IO.FileSystem.dll'.  Cannot match image without load anything option set
TargetComposition: Found original image for module 'System.IO.FileSystem.dll' at '\\symbolsrv.xyz.com\symbols\System.IO.FileSystem.dll\E7FD7CA5a000\System.IO.FileSystem.dll' with matching header information
ELFBin: No build id is found for module 'HtmlSanitizer.dll'.  Cannot match image without load anything option set
TargetComposition: Unable to find any original image for module 'HtmlSanitizer.dll'
SYMSRV:  BYINDEX: 0x1C
         \\symbolsrv.xyz.com\symbols*\\symbolsrv.xyz.com\symbols\xyz*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
         HtmlSanitizer.dll
         E5F82C6212000
SYMSRV:  UNC: \\symbolsrv.xyz.com\symbols\HtmlSanitizer.dll\E5F82C6212000\HtmlSanitizer.dll - path not found
SYMSRV:  UNC: \\symbolsrv.xyz.com\symbols\HtmlSanitizer.dll\E5F82C6212000\HtmlSanitizer.dl_ - path not found
SYMSRV:  UNC: \\symbolsrv.xyz.com\symbols\HtmlSanitizer.dll\E5F82C6212000\file.ptr - path not found
SYMSRV:  UNC: \\symbolsrv.xyz.com\symbols\xyz\HtmlSanitizer.dll\E5F82C6212000\HtmlSanitizer.dll - path not found
SYMSRV:  UNC: \\symbolsrv.xyz.com\symbols\xyz\HtmlSanitizer.dll\E5F82C6212000\HtmlSanitizer.dl_ - path not found
SYMSRV:  UNC: \\symbolsrv.xyz.com\symbols\xyz\HtmlSanitizer.dll\E5F82C6212000\file.ptr - path not found
SYMSRV:  HTTPGET: /download/symbols/HtmlSanitizer.dll/E5F82C6212000/HtmlSanitizer.dll
SYMSRV:  HttpQueryInfo: 80190194 - HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND
SYMSRV:  HTTPGET: /download/symbols/HtmlSanitizer.dll/E5F82C6212000/HtmlSanitizer.dl_
SYMSRV:  HttpQueryInfo: 80190194 - HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND
SYMSRV:  HTTPGET: /download/symbols/HtmlSanitizer.dll/E5F82C6212000/file.ptr
SYMSRV:  HttpQueryInfo: 80190194 - HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND
SYMSRV:  RESULT: 0x80190194
DBGHELP: c:\utils\windbg\x64\HtmlSanitizer.dll - file not found
DBGHELP: c:\utils\windbg\x64\HtmlSanitizer.dll - file not found
DBGENG:  /app/HtmlSanitizer.dll - Image mapping disallowed by non-local path.
Unable to load image /app/HtmlSanitizer.dll, Win32 error 0n2
ELFBin: No build id is found for module 'OrchardCore.Features.dll'.  Cannot match image without load anything option set
TargetComposition: Unable to find any original image for module 'OrchardCore.Features.dll'
SYMSRV:  BYINDEX: 0x1E
         \\symbolsrv.xyz.com\symbols*\\symbolsrv.xyz.com\symbols\xyz*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
         OrchardCore.Features.dll
         9D25DFDD22000
SYMSRV:  UNC: \\symbolsrv.xyz.com\symbols\OrchardCore.Features.dll\9D25DFDD22000\OrchardCore.Features.dll - path not found
SYMSRV:  UNC: \\symbolsrv.xyz.com\symbols\OrchardCore.Features.dll\9D25DFDD22000\OrchardCore.Features.dl_ - path not found
SYMSRV:  UNC: \\symbolsrv.xyz.com\symbols\OrchardCore.Features.dll\9D25DFDD22000\file.ptr - path not found
SYMSRV:  UNC: \\symbolsrv.xyz.com\symbols\xyz\OrchardCore.Features.dll\9D25DFDD22000\OrchardCore.Features.dll - path not found
SYMSRV:  UNC: \\symbolsrv.xyz.com\symbols\xyz\OrchardCore.Features.dll\9D25DFDD22000\OrchardCore.Features.dl_ - path not found
SYMSRV:  UNC: \\symbolsrv.xyz.com\symbols\xyz\OrchardCore.Features.dll\9D25DFDD22000\file.ptr - path not found
SYMSRV:  HTTPGET: /download/symbols/OrchardCore.Features.dll/9D25DFDD22000/OrchardCore.Features.dll
SYMSRV:  HttpQueryInfo: 80190194 - HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND
SYMSRV:  HTTPGET: /download/symbols/OrchardCore.Features.dll/9D25DFDD22000/OrchardCore.Features.dl_
SYMSRV:  HttpQueryInfo: 80190194 - HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND
SYMSRV:  HTTPGET: /download/symbols/OrchardCore.Features.dll/9D25DFDD22000/file.ptr
SYMSRV:  HttpQueryInfo: 80190194 - HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND
SYMSRV:  RESULT: 0x80190194
DBGHELP: c:\utils\windbg\x64\OrchardCore.Features.dll - file not found
DBGHELP: c:\utils\windbg\x64\OrchardCore.Features.dll - file not found
DBGENG:  /app/OrchardCore.Features.dll - Image mapping disallowed by non-local path.
Unable to load image /app/OrchardCore.Features.dll, Win32 error 0n2
ELFBin: No build id is found for module 'xyz.Resources.dll'.  Cannot match image without load anything option set
TargetComposition: Unable to find any original image for module 'xyz.Resources.dll'
SYMSRV:  BYINDEX: 0x20
         \\symbolsrv.xyz.com\symbols*\\symbolsrv.xyz.com\symbols\xyz*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
         xyz.Resources.dll
         F98B149189a000
SYMSRV:  UNC: \\symbolsrv.xyz.com\symbols\xyz.Resources.dll\F98B149189a000\xyz.Resources.dll - path not found
SYMSRV:  UNC: \\symbolsrv.xyz.com\symbols\xyz.Resources.dll\F98B149189a000\xyz.Resources.dl_ - path not found
SYMSRV:  UNC: \\symbolsrv.xyz.com\symbols\xyz.Resources.dll\F98B149189a000\file.ptr - path not found
SYMSRV:  UNC: \\symbolsrv.xyz.com\symbols\xyz\xyz.Resources.dll\F98B149189a000\xyz.Resources.dll - path not found
SYMSRV:  UNC: \\symbolsrv.xyz.com\symbols\xyz\xyz.Resources.dll\F98B149189a000\xyz.Resources.dl_ - path not found
SYMSRV:  UNC: \\symbolsrv.xyz.com\symbols\xyz\xyz.Resources.dll\F98B149189a000\file.ptr - path not found
SYMSRV:  HTTPGET: /download/symbols/xyz.Resources.dll/F98B149189a000/xyz.Resources.dll
SYMSRV:  HttpQueryInfo: 80190194 - HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND
SYMSRV:  HTTPGET: /download/symbols/xyz.Resources.dll/F98B149189a000/xyz.Resources.dl_
SYMSRV:  HttpQueryInfo: 80190194 - HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND
SYMSRV:  HTTPGET: /download/symbols/xyz.Resources.dll/F98B149189a000/file.ptr
SYMSRV:  HttpQueryInfo: 80190194 - HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND
SYMSRV:  RESULT: 0x80190194
DBGHELP: c:\utils\windbg\x64\xyz.Resources.dll - file not found
DBGHELP: c:\utils\windbg\x64\xyz.Resources.dll - file not found
DBGENG:  /app/xyz.Resources.dll - Image mapping disallowed by non-local path.
Unable to load image /app/xyz.Resources.dll, Win32 error 0n2
ELFBin: No build id is found for module 'xyz.WidgetInfrastructure.dll'.  Cannot match image without load anything option set
TargetComposition: Unable to find any original image for module 'xyz.WidgetInfrastructure.dll'
SYMSRV:  BYINDEX: 0x22
         \\symbolsrv.xyz.com\symbols*\\symbolsrv.xyz.com\symbols\xyz*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
         xyz.WidgetInfrastructure.dll
         87CD12673a4000
SYMSRV:  UNC: \\symbolsrv.xyz.com\symbols\xyz.WidgetInfrastructure.dll\87CD12673a4000\xyz.WidgetInfrastructure.dll - path not found
SYMSRV:  UNC: \\symbolsrv.xyz.com\symbols\xyz.WidgetInfrastructure.dll\87CD12673a4000\xyz.WidgetInfrastructure.dl_ - path not found
SYMSRV:  UNC: \\symbolsrv.xyz.com\symbols\xyz.WidgetInfrastructure.dll\87CD12673a4000\file.ptr - path not found
SYMSRV:  UNC: \\symbolsrv.xyz.com\symbols\xyz\xyz.WidgetInfrastructure.dll\87CD12673a4000\xyz.WidgetInfrastructure.dll - path not found
SYMSRV:  UNC: \\symbolsrv.xyz.com\symbols\xyz\xyz.WidgetInfrastructure.dll\87CD12673a4000\xyz.WidgetInfrastructure.dl_ - path not found
SYMSRV:  UNC: \\symbolsrv.xyz.com\symbols\xyz\xyz.WidgetInfrastructure.dll\87CD12673a4000\file.ptr - path not found
SYMSRV:  HTTPGET: /download/symbols/xyz.WidgetInfrastructure.dll/87CD12673a4000/xyz.WidgetInfrastructure.dll
SYMSRV:  HttpQueryInfo: 80190194 - HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND
SYMSRV:  HTTPGET: /download/symbols/xyz.WidgetInfrastructure.dll/87CD12673a4000/xyz.WidgetInfrastructure.dl_
SYMSRV:  HttpQueryInfo: 80190194 - HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND
SYMSRV:  HTTPGET: /download/symbols/xyz.WidgetInfrastructure.dll/87CD12673a4000/file.ptr
SYMSRV:  HttpQueryInfo: 80190194 - HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND
SYMSRV:  RESULT: 0x80190194
DBGHELP: c:\utils\windbg\x64\xyz.WidgetInfrastructure.dll - file not found
DBGHELP: c:\utils\windbg\x64\xyz.WidgetInfrastructure.dll - file not found
DBGENG:  /app/xyz.WidgetInfrastructure.dll - Image mapping disallowed by non-local path.
Unable to load image /app/xyz.WidgetInfrastructure.dll, Win32 error 0n2
ELFBin: No build id is found for module 'OpenIddict.Core.dll'.  Cannot match image without load anything option set
TargetComposition: Unable to find any original image for module 'OpenIddict.Core.dll'
SYMSRV:  BYINDEX: 0x24
         \\symbolsrv.xyz.com\symbols*\\symbolsrv.xyz.com\symbols\xyz*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
         OpenIddict.Core.dll
         FFC8D9C558000
SYMSRV:  UNC: \\symbolsrv.xyz.com\symbols\OpenIddict.Core.dll\FFC8D9C558000\OpenIddict.Core.dll - path not found
SYMSRV:  UNC: \\symbolsrv.xyz.com\symbols\OpenIddict.Core.dll\FFC8D9C558000\OpenIddict.Core.dl_ - path not found
SYMSRV:  UNC: \\symbolsrv.xyz.com\symbols\OpenIddict.Core.dll\FFC8D9C558000\file.ptr - path not found
SYMSRV:  UNC: \\symbolsrv.xyz.com\symbols\xyz\OpenIddict.Core.dll\FFC8D9C558000\OpenIddict.Core.dll - path not found
SYMSRV:  UNC: \\symbolsrv.xyz.com\symbols\xyz\OpenIddict.Core.dll\FFC8D9C558000\OpenIddict.Core.dl_ - path not found
SYMSRV:  UNC: \\symbolsrv.xyz.com\symbols\xyz\OpenIddict.Core.dll\FFC8D9C558000\file.ptr - path not found
SYMSRV:  HTTPGET: /download/symbols/OpenIddict.Core.dll/FFC8D9C558000/OpenIddict.Core.dll
SYMSRV:  HttpQueryInfo: 80190194 - HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND
SYMSRV:  HTTPGET: /download/symbols/OpenIddict.Core.dll/FFC8D9C558000/OpenIddict.Core.dl_
SYMSRV:  HttpQueryInfo: 80190194 - HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND
SYMSRV:  HTTPGET: /download/symbols/OpenIddict.Core.dll/FFC8D9C558000/file.ptr
SYMSRV:  HttpQueryInfo: 80190194 - HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND
SYMSRV:  RESULT: 0x80190194
DBGHELP: c:\utils\windbg\x64\OpenIddict.Core.dll - file not found
DBGHELP: c:\utils\windbg\x64\OpenIddict.Core.dll - file not found
DBGENG:  /app/OpenIddict.Core.dll - Image mapping disallowed by non-local path.
Unable to load image /app/OpenIddict.Core.dll, Win32 error 0n2
ELFBin: No build id is found for module 'xyz.Cms.Web.dll'.  Cannot match image without load anything option set
TargetComposition: Unable to find any original image for module 'xyz.Cms.Web.dll'
SYMSRV:  BYINDEX: 0x26
         \\symbolsrv.xyz.com\symbols*\\symbolsrv.xyz.com\symbols\xyz*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
         xyz.Cms.Web.dll
         F5A44AFD24000
SYMSRV:  UNC: \\symbolsrv.xyz.com\symbols\xyz.Cms.Web.dll\F5A44AFD24000\xyz.Cms.Web.dll - path not found
SYMSRV:  UNC: \\symbolsrv.xyz.com\symbols\xyz.Cms.Web.dll\F5A44AFD24000\xyz.Cms.Web.dl_ - path not found
SYMSRV:  UNC: \\symbolsrv.xyz.com\symbols\xyz.Cms.Web.dll\F5A44AFD24000\file.ptr - path not found
SYMSRV:  UNC: \\symbolsrv.xyz.com\symbols\xyz\xyz.Cms.Web.dll\F5A44AFD24000\xyz.Cms.Web.dll - path not found
SYMSRV:  UNC: \\symbolsrv.xyz.com\symbols\xyz\xyz.Cms.Web.dll\F5A44AFD24000\xyz.Cms.Web.dl_ - path not found
SYMSRV:  UNC: \\symbolsrv.xyz.com\symbols\xyz\xyz.Cms.Web.dll\F5A44AFD24000\file.ptr - path not found
SYMSRV:  HTTPGET: /download/symbols/xyz.Cms.Web.dll/F5A44AFD24000/xyz.Cms.Web.dll
SYMSRV:  HttpQueryInfo: 80190194 - HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND
SYMSRV:  HTTPGET: /download/symbols/xyz.Cms.Web.dll/F5A44AFD24000/xyz.Cms.Web.dl_
SYMSRV:  HttpQueryInfo: 80190194 - HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND
SYMSRV:  HTTPGET: /download/symbols/xyz.Cms.Web.dll/F5A44AFD24000/file.ptr
SYMSRV:  HttpQueryInfo: 80190194 - HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND
SYMSRV:  RESULT: 0x80190194
DBGHELP: c:\utils\windbg\x64\xyz.Cms.Web.dll - file not found
DBGHELP: c:\utils\windbg\x64\xyz.Cms.Web.dll - file not found
DBGENG:  /app/xyz.Cms.Web.dll - Image mapping disallowed by non-local path.
Unable to load image /app/xyz.Cms.Web.dll, Win32 error 0n2
ELFBin: No build id is found for module 'System.Reflection.dll'.  Cannot match image without load anything option set
TargetComposition: Found original image for module 'System.Reflection.dll' at '\\symbolsrv.xyz.com\symbols\System.Reflection.dll\D0CBF6CF8000\System.Reflection.dll' with matching header information
ELFBin: No build id is found for module 'System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.dll'.  Cannot match image without load anything option set
TargetComposition: Found original image for module 'System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.dll' at '\\symbolsrv.xyz.com\symbols\System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.dll\CA5E4DE48000\System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.dll' with matching header information
ELFBin: No build id is found for module 'xyz.ContentLocalization.dll'.  Cannot match image without load anything option set
TargetComposition: Unable to find any original image for module 'xyz.ContentLocalization.dll'
SYMSRV:  BYINDEX: 0x2A
         \\symbolsrv.xyz.com\symbols*\\symbolsrv.xyz.com\symbols\xyz*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
         xyz.ContentLocalization.dll
         C378E733a000
SYMSRV:  UNC: \\symbolsrv.xyz.com\symbols\xyz.ContentLocalization.dll\C378E733a000\xyz.ContentLocalization.dll - path not found
SYMSRV:  UNC: \\symbolsrv.xyz.com\symbols\xyz.ContentLocalization.dll\C378E733a000\xyz.ContentLocalization.dl_ - path not found
SYMSRV:  UNC: \\symbolsrv.xyz.com\symbols\xyz.ContentLocalization.dll\C378E733a000\file.ptr - path not found
SYMSRV:  UNC: \\symbolsrv.xyz.com\symbols\xyz\xyz.ContentLocalization.dll\C378E733a000\xyz.ContentLocalization.dll - path not found
SYMSRV:  UNC: \\symbolsrv.xyz.com\symbols\xyz\xyz.ContentLocalization.dll\C378E733a000\xyz.ContentLocalization.dl_ - path not found
SYMSRV:  UNC: \\symbolsrv.xyz.com\symbols\xyz\xyz.ContentLocalization.dll\C378E733a000\file.ptr - path not found
SYMSRV:  HTTPGET: /download/symbols/xyz.ContentLocalization.dll/C378E733a000/xyz.ContentLocalization.dll
SYMSRV:  HttpQueryInfo: 80190194 - HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND
SYMSRV:  HTTPGET: /download/symbols/xyz.ContentLocalization.dll/C378E733a000/xyz.ContentLocalization.dl_
SYMSRV:  HttpQueryInfo: 80190194 - HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND
SYMSRV:  HTTPGET: /download/symbols/xyz.ContentLocalization.dll/C378E733a000/file.ptr
SYMSRV:  HttpQueryInfo: 80190194 - HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND
SYMSRV:  RESULT: 0x80190194
DBGHELP: c:\utils\windbg\x64\xyz.ContentLocalization.dll - file not found
DBGHELP: c:\utils\windbg\x64\xyz.ContentLocalization.dll - file not found
DBGENG:  /app/xyz.ContentLocalization.dll - Image mapping disallowed by non-local path.
Unable to load image /app/xyz.ContentLocalization.dll, Win32 error 0n2

"xyz_common" was not found in the image list.
Debugger will attempt to load "xyz_common" at given base 00000000`00000000.

Please provide the full image name, including the extension (i.e. kernel32.dll)
for more reliable results.Base address and size overrides can be given as
.reload <image.ext>=<base>,<size>.
DBGENG:  xyz_common - Partial symbol image load missing image info
DBGHELP: No header for xyz_common.  Searching for dbg file
DBGHELP: .\xyz_common.dbg - file not found
DBGHELP: xyz_common missing debug info.  Searching for pdb anyway
DBGHELP: Can't use symbol server for xyz_common.pdb - no header information available
DBGHELP: xyz_common.pdb - file not found
*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for xyz_common
ELFBin: Head page of module 'xyz_common' is not mapped in core.
ELFBin: Head page of module 'xyz_common' is not mapped in core.
ELFBin: No build id is found for module 'xyz_common'.  Cannot match image without load anything option set
ELFBin: Head page of module 'xyz_common' is not mapped in core.
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for xyz_common
DBGHELP: xyz_common_0 - no symbols loaded
Unable to add module at 00000000`00000000
0:000> lmvm xyz_common
Browse full module list
start             end                 module name
00007454`16df8000 00007454`16e70000   xyz_Common   (deferred)             
    Image path: /app/xyz.Common.dll
    Image name: xyz.Common.dll
    Browse all global symbols  functions  data
    Has CLR image header, track-debug-data flag not set
    Timestamp:        ***** Invalid (9FC82936)
    CheckSum:         00000000
    ImageSize:        (header) 0007E000, (mapped) 0x00078000
    Translations:     0000.04b0 0000.04e4 0409.04b0 0409.04e4
    Information from resource tables:
```

Comment: "I am unable to load the symbols because of it"; not sure that the `!dh` and symbol loading problems are related. Could you do a `!sym noisy` and then force a reload of the symbols for that DLL with `.reload /f /s <module_name>`. Also a `lmDvm <module_name_no_extension>`  (the output of the aforementioned commands would be a great addition to your post to diagnose the symbol problem).

Comment: Sure, I will do that. However, being unable to read the debug directory means it cannot see the guid that links binary with its pdb. That prevents correctly identifying the pdb. I, of course, already tried these commands, but let me repeat and paste their output.

Comment: Thanks for the commands output. This is confusing, `ELFBin: Head page of module 'xyz_common' is not mapped in core.` would tend to point to the headers are not being present in the dump, but since you extracted the image from the dump itself, there's definitely something weird going on here. I'm out of ideas :|

Comment: may be you could check with dumpchk  Module list stream and memory list stream and confimr if the page is present

Comment: also i am a bit confused it seems the debug dir RVA is at 0x787c4 and you dump just 78000 bytes   iirc dumpbin will be comfortable parsing partially dumped files

Comment: I cannot explain it either. Maybe I need to use a different logic to determine the size of the dll. My goal was to show that `dumpbin` reads the debug directory fine, but not the windbg. The actual size of the image could be larger, in which case I do not know why `lmvm` would report it incorrectly.

Comment: lmvm says 7e000  but mapped 78000  so probably some thing seems to be not mapped

Comment: also the timestamps in newer files are a reproducible hash atleast on windows uisng /B repro (which is invalid in your lmvm output)

Comment: So what does it all mean? The dump is open just fine by Visual Studio. So I assume it is a valid dump. I may have dumped only portion of it to the dll, but `dumpbin` happily displayed the headers and the debug directory is correct. So why the latest WinDBG cannot read it?

Comment: i dont know just guessing also it seems your target is 14C machine (i386) (try vertarget) and you are loading it in x64 windbg  have you tried the x86 windbg ?  the x86 msix ?

Comment: Yup, tried both flavors of the debugger - same result. Also, I am pretty sure the 64 is the correct version. The dumps from this process take up more than 4 GB